# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following function:

```
 const UseFeature = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  const features = useContext(FeatureFlags);


   if (features === null) {
   throw new Error('You must wrap your components in a FeatureProvider.');
  }
  return Array.isArray(features) ? features.includes(name) : features[name];
 };

 export default UseFeature;
```

I call this function on another component :

```
const hasV1 = UseFeature('v1');
```

I get this error which I don't understand

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.  
 TS2345
```

Yet `'V1'` is indeed a string element.

Have you ever had this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V1` is a `string` but `UseFeature` wants a `{ name: string; }`

You have two options.

You could change the type when you call `UseFeature`

```
const hasV1 = UseFeature({name: 'v1'});
```

or change the declaration of `UseFeature` to

```
const UseFeature = (name: string ) => {
```

And still call it with `const hasV1 = UseFeature('v1');`

In this second example you are no longer destructuring an object. With the function using only one property / parameter I prefer the second solution more.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `UseFeature` destructures `name`, so is expecting that when you call the function. You've just passed a `string`:

```js
const hasV1 = UseFeature('v1');
```

It is expecting an object:

```js
const hasV1 = UseFeature({name: 'v1'});
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
const data:any= { name:'v1' }
const hasV1 = UseFeature(data);
```